# Question about end caps on Pex lines for Washer in new house

Tags: plumbing, water, pex, plumbing-fixture, washer

I just purchased a new home and the washer and dryer are in the basement, I plan to learn how to run pex soon although only know a little about it now. I went to go hookup my washer today and there are these two caps that are on the hot and cold washer lines that hang down from the ceiling.

They are not threaded so I can't screw them off so I'm not really sure how to remove them.

[image]

Also the lines are 1/2 inch and my washer hoses and connections on my washer are 3/4 inch, I"m assuming once I get them off I can buy a pex 1/2 inch to 34 inch fitting?

Answer (score 1):

If those were crimped-on end-caps you'd have to cut them off - but they look like "sharkbite" fittings, which can be removed. If you lack the special tool, close an adjustable wrench down to the size of the pipe, and use it to push the tan collar into the fitting.

Search for "sharkbite adjustable wrench trick" or "how to remove a sharkbite" if that's unclear. If all else fails, cut them off. Try to be sure the water is shut off first.

99.9% of washer hookups are "garden hose thread" so I suspect 3/4 pipe thread would be the wrong choice.

Comment: Thanks, and not knowing much about pex can I buy 1/2 inch to 3/4 fittings for them and just plug them in.

Comment: Thanks, I've done a lot of research today and think i have everything figured out, as you mentioned those are sharkbite so I'm going to get the little tool to remove them then I'm purchasing a crimping tool and going to crimp on the new fittings that I need for the washer.